# sorting with coreutil's sort

Tags: sorting, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to sort a table based on the first value from smallest to largest with the gnu-coreutils sort command.

My table looks something like this:

file.txt

```
100,0.8,0.323, ... some more data
2,0.323,0,323, ...
4, ...
53, ...
.
.
121, ...
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
sort -n -k 1 file.txt
```

but I get things like...

```
10,0,10,10
100,9,1,10
101,9,2,11
102,9,3,12
103,9,4,13
104,9,5,14
105,9,6,15
106,9,7,16
107,9,8,17
108,9,9,18
21,1,10,11
32,2,10,12
43,3,10,13
54,4,10,14
```

I want the logical numerical order.

Ted.

Comment: 22,33,44 looks good to me - what order did you want those to appear in?

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention.. well the thing is there are numbers such as:
21,22,23,24... before 33 and it is not showing those up... they are probably somewhere else in the sorted file.

Comment: I also wanted to ask, my default sort command comes from /usr/bin/sort, but that sort does not have the random sort which I like to use. I want to use the sort from my coreutils installation, but I don't want to add all core utils to my path. I tried this.. but it did not work:
alias sort='/sw/lib/coreutils/bin/sort'
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct invocation of `sort` might look like

```
$ sort -n -t , -k 1,1 file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-n`      sort numerically
- `-t ,`    comma is field separator
- `-k 1,1`  sort on the first field
- `file.txt` input file

Invoking the above given program gives

> 10,0,10,10
>   21,1,10,11
>   32,2,10,12
>   43,3,10,13
>   54,4,10,14
>   100,9,1,10
>   101,9,2,11
>   102,9,3,12
>   103,9,4,13
>   104,9,5,14
>   105,9,6,15
>   106,9,7,16
>   107,9,8,17
>   108,9,9,18

When sorting by fields it is very handy to use `--debug` option, just to make sure that sort works as expected.